# "Внизу маски" вместо "под маской" - правильно или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Задался вопросом, можно ли написать "внизу маски"? Как бы хочу описать, что под ней, но повторятся не хочется. "Внизу маски" - правильное ли выражение? Можно ли употреблять эти слова вместе и подходят ли они в смысловом плане?

Comment: Это означало бы "в нижней части маски". Для разнообразия можно попробовать "за маской" или "по ту сторону маски".

Answer (score 3):

Нет, неправильно.

1. Низ маски = нижняя часть маски (внизу маски — в ее нижнем отделе, но никак не под ней).

*Великий экспериментатор Jacques Plante, выступая за «Блюзменов», **прорезал внизу маски еще пару отверстий...***
Е. Стариков. Маскарад. Бесконечная история хоккейных вратарских масок

***Внизу маски*** был подклеен валик из скрученной в трубочку резины.
С. Гагаев. Записки водолазного старшины

2. Если не нравится "под маской", то можно использовать "за маской" (в зависимости от контекста, конечно):

*За маской угадывались черты лица лейтенанта Ертсена, однако и костюм, и танец были в высшей мере женственны.*
Р. Амундсен. Моя жизнь. Южный полюс

*За маской скрывались внимательно его рассматривающие глаза.*
А. Сухих. Красная розочка

Answer (score 0):

Внизу маски - это в нижней части маски, никуда не деться.

> Можно ли употреблять эти слова вместе и подходят ли они в смысловом
> плане?

Да ни за что!

Очень сомнительно для меня самой: *снизу, с изнанки*; с оборотной стороны? Может, как-то примериться к слову *подоплёка*?

Всё-таки придётся смириться с "под маской"...

---

[Владимир Высоцкий](http://www.bards.ru/archives/part.php?id=15350)

Смеюсь навзрыд, как у кривых зеркал,

Меня, должно быть, ловко разыграли:

Крючки носов и до ушей оскал —

Как на венецианском карнавале!

---

Вокруг меня смыкается кольцо,

Меня хватают, вовлекают в пляску.

Так-так, моё нормальное лицо

Все, вероятно, приняли за маску.

---

Петарды, конфетти... Но всё не так!

И маски на меня глядят с укором,

Они кричат, что я опять не в такт,

Что наступаю на ноги партнёрам.

---

Что делать мне — бежать, да поскорей?

А может, вместе с ними веселиться?..

Надеюсь я — ***под масками*** зверей

Бывают человеческие лица.

---

Все в масках, в париках — все как один,

Кто — сказочен, а кто — литературен...

Сосед мой слева — грустный арлекин,

Другой — палач, а каждый третий — дурень.

---

Один — себя старался обелить,

Другой — лицо скрывает от огласки,

А кто — уже не в силах отличить

Своё лицо от непременной маски.

---

Я в хоровод вступаю, хохоча,

И всё-таки мне неспокойно с ними:

А вдруг кому-то маска палача

Понравится — и он её не снимет?

---

Вдруг арлекин навеки загрустит,

Любуясь сам своим лицом печальным;

Что, если дурень свой дурацкий вид

Так и забудет на лице нормальном?!

---

За масками гоняюсь по пятам,

Но ни одну не попрошу открыться:

Что, если маски сброшены, а там —

Всё те же полумаски-полулица?

---

Как доброго лица не прозевать,

Как честных отличить наверняка мне?

Все научились маски надевать,

Чтоб не разбить своё лицо о камни.

---

Я в тайну масок всё-таки проник,

Уверен я, что мой анализ точен,

Что маски равнодушья у иных —

Защита от плевков и от пощёчин.

---

1970